# How can i create a sub-group in chatter ? If not ? what is the solution ?

Tags: administration, chatter, developer, chatter-groups

i am badly in need of this feature , i.e to have sub groups under a group in chatter. I tried alot but could not find the solution. Could anyone guide me.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KqKqAAK       Its running under ideas unfortunately.

Comment: Solution needed badly my dear friend ..,

Comment: lets hope someone on this community comes with some innovative idea to do this.Myself stumped on this question !!!!!

Comment: What's the use case for needing a sub-group? How does a regular group not meet the requirements?